# Polymorphism: source and target not compatible

Tags: class, dynamic, polymorphism, compatibility, attachment

I have a question about polymorphic assignments.
Let's assume this declarations:

```
CAR car;
MERCEDES mercedes;
//MERCEDES inherits from CAR

car = new MERCEDES(classA);
mercedes = car
```

Is the last assignment possible? I thought that the first assignment changes the type of **car** into **MERCEDES** and so the last assignment would be right.
But in the sheets I have it shows that it doesn't compile because the source of assignment and the target are not compatible.
Is this right? And why is this so?

Comment: `car = new MERCEDES(...)` doesn't change the *type* of the `car` variable; it's still `CAR`. The assignment is valid because `MERCEDES` **is a** `CAR`, but it doesn't change the fact that `car` is not guaranteed to be any particular `CAR` subclass.

Comment: That means that the static type stays CAR while the dynamic type is MERCEDES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sheets are right, because a `CAR` is not necessarily a `MERCEDES`. It just happens to be true in your case, but think about the general case.

There could be plenty of car types, and the compiler can not assure that the assignment expression is true at all.

Comment: Ah okkey! But the first assignment changes the type of car into MERCEDES, this is right?

Comment: @Ergo all Mercedes are cars, but not all cars are Mercedes.

Comment: Yeah I got it till there, it was more like a general question the one I made now. But it's clear now, thanks

Comment: @Ergo not sure I understood the question about first assignment.. which one do you refer as the first? the instantiation (which also entails an assignment, or the second one?) any way, please do mark the question as answered if you are satisfied with it.